# how to deal with formatted number (currency) in textfield?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, number-formatting

```
struct PriceField: View {


    @ObservedObject var textFieldManager = TextFieldManager()
    @State var number : Double = 0
    @State var inputString  = ""


    var body: some View {


        HStack{
//            Text(format(num: textFieldManager.number))
            Text("\(textFieldManager.number)")
            TextField("RM", value: $textFieldManager.number, formatter: NumberFormatter.currency){
                    UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
            }

            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
//            .keyboardType(.numberPad)



        }
    }
}


extension NumberFormatter {
    static var currency: NumberFormatter {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ms_MY")
        return formatter
    }

}




func format(num: Double) -> String{
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ms_MY")
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency

    if let formattedAmount = formatter.string(from: num as NSNumber) {
        return formattedAmount
    }
    else{
        return "Formatting error ... "
    }

}



class TextFieldManager: ObservableObject {

    @Published var number : Double = 0 {
        didSet{
            print("change from:", oldValue, "to:", "\(number)")
        }

    }


}
```

1. When I type RM12.34255 and press 'Return', the textfield shows
   RM12.34 ( which is formatted in the desired decimals). However, it
   doesn't update my class property to RM12.34, instead, it gets
   updated with RM12.34255. How do I get around with this?
2. It seems that the currency title (RM) can get erased and there is a
   chance where users can input a number **without** the current symbol
   and it yields error "MultiLineTextView[31301:771480] [SwiftUI] The
   value “12.34255” is invalid.". Would it be possible to make the text
   "RM" in-erasable in the textfield?

**Updated Code:**

```
func format(num: Double) -> Double{
    let doubleStr = String(format: "%.2f", num) // "3.14"
    let doubleNum =  Double(doubleStr)!
    print("doubleStr \(doubleStr), doubleNum \(doubleNum)")
    return doubleNum

}



class TextFieldManager: ObservableObject {

    @Published var number : Double = 0 {
        didSet{
            print("change from:", oldValue, "to:", "\(number)")
            formattedNumber = format(num: number)
            print("formattedNumber is : \(formattedNumber)")

        }


    }

    @Published var formattedNumber : Double = 0



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding question (1), understand that formatting only changes the "looks" of the number, as shown in the TextField. It does not change the value. The value is still a Double. This is why your class property "number" will be a Double.
How do I get around with this? You don't, this is normal behaviour. To display this class property "number" the way you want it, use the NumberFormatter or any formatter you want.

Regarding question (2), try "formatter.isLenient = true" as shown in the following code.

This is the code I used for testing.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
   PriceField()
}
}

struct PriceField: View {
@ObservedObject var textFieldManager = TextFieldManager()
var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Text("\(textFieldManager.number)")
        TextField("RM", value: $textFieldManager.number, formatter: NumberFormatter.currency)
    }
}
}

extension NumberFormatter {
static var currency: NumberFormatter {
    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.isLenient = true  //  <--- works without the currency symbol
    formatter.numberStyle = .currency
    formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ms_MY")
    return formatter
}
}

func format(num: Double) -> String{
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ms_MY")
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
if let formattedAmount = formatter.string(from: num as NSNumber) {
    return formattedAmount
} else {
    return "Formatting error ... "
}
}

class TextFieldManager: ObservableObject {
@Published var number : Double = 0 {
    didSet{
        print("---> change from:", oldValue, "to:", "\(number)")
    }
}
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: for question (1), alright, I see. So I just create another class property 'formattedNumber' on top of 'number' to work around with this. For question (2), well, that works. Is there really no way to make the currency symbol to be here, not to be erased at all time?

Comment: adding formatter.isLenient = true  makes the current symbol to reappear once 'return' button is hit, if it gets erased during editing. However, it might be a desired property to retain the symbol during user is editing the textfield

Comment: one way to deal with the currency symbol, is to put nothing in the TextField("", ...) and put a permanent Text("RM") in front of it.

Comment: I just tried, that didn't work. Would you mind to show how did you do it?  The textfield alignment is trailing by the way.              Text("RM")
            TextField("", value: $textFieldManager.number, formatter: NumberFormatter.currency)
            {
                    UIApplication.shared.endEditing()
            }

            .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)

Comment: something like this;       HStack {  Spacer()
            Text("RM")
            TextField("", value: $textFieldManager.number, formatter: NumberFormatter())
       }

Comment: this will create ( even with the spacer() ) a wide space between the RM and the number. the number and the symbol should sit next to each other without space, appearing at the right hand corner.

Comment: try this:         HStack (spacing: 4) {
            Spacer()
            Text("RM").frame(width: 45, height: 45, alignment: .trailing)
            TextField("", value: $textFieldManager.number, formatter: NumberFormatter())
            .frame(width: 123, height: 45, alignment: .leading)
        }

Comment: well, I wish to have the textfield cursor appearing from the right-most corner of the screen. That being said, I guess the alignment for the textfield has to be .trailing? your solution creates a textfield that appears to be leading ( leaving space from the right hand side )